# Difference between cancel and uninterruptibleCancel (from the Async library)

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency

#### Context:

I'm trying to understand the difference between [`cancel`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/async-2.2.1/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:cancel) and [`uninterruptibleCancel`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/async-2.2.1/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:uninterruptibleCancel) from the `Control.Concurent.Async` package. I believe it has something to do with the underlying concepts of [`mask`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:mask) , [`uninterruptibleMask`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:uninterruptibleMask), and [interruptible operations](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Exception.html#g:13). Here's what I have understood so for:

- Asynchronous exceptions are thrown by thread-A, but need to be handled by thread-B. This is precisely what [`throwTo`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:throwTo) does. In some way, this can also be *considered* as a form of inter-thread communication.
- Asynchronous exceptions are used by one thread to kill/cancel another thread.
- Handling aysnchronous exceptions creates a problem in the target/receiving thread, because one usually doesn't expect exceptions to be raised at any random point in the code. One puts `try` / `catch` around certain operations and *expects*/handles only certain exceptions. But, Asynchronous exceptions can be delivered when the target thread could be at any point in the execution.
- `mask` allows use to protect critical sections in the target/receiving thread from delivery of asynchronous exceptions. The operation protected by `mask` doesn't need to deal with asynchronous-exceptions till the point it calls `restore`.

At this point `uninterruptibleMask` comes into the picture, and I start losing the plot. I thought the whole point of `mask` was to NOT deliver asynchronous-exceptions while executing a protected piece of code. However, here is what the docs say about "interruptible actions":

> It is useful to think of mask not as a way to completely prevent asynchronous exceptions, but as a way to switch from asynchronous mode to polling mode. The main difficulty with asynchronous exceptions is that they normally can occur anywhere, but within a mask an asynchronous exception is only raised by operations that are interruptible (or call other interruptible operations). In many cases these operations may themselves raise exceptions, such as I/O errors, so the caller will usually be prepared to handle exceptions arising from the operation anyway. **To perform an explicit poll for asynchronous exceptions inside mask, use allowInterrupt.**

#### Questions:

- Even within a code-block protected by `mask`, if there are some points where it is safe to handle asynchronous-exceptions, one can call `allowInterrupt`. This *implicitly* means, that, unless `allowInterrupt` is called, asynchronous exceptions will NOT be delivered while executing `mask`ed code. What, then, is the purpose of `uninterruptibleMask`?
- Consequently, what is the need for `uninterruptibleCancel`? IIUC, thread A is trying to cancel thread B, but thread A, itself, is trying to protect itself from some sort of asynchronous exceptions, which may possibly be initiated by a third thread C, right? In the code for `cancel` (given below), which part is so critical that it needs the ultimate form of protection from asynchronous exceptions? Isn't `throwTo` an atomic/masked operation itself? Further, even if an asynchronous-exception *is delivered* to thread-A while executing `waitCatch`, what difference does it make? Actually, if I think about it, why do we need to even `mask` this code in the first place (let alone, `uninterruptibleMask`) ?

```
cancel a@(Async t _) = throwTo t AsyncCancelled <* waitCatch a
```

Answer (score 4):

Under no masking, asynchronous exceptions can happen wherever. Under `mask`, asynchronous exceptions can only appear from interruptible actions (which are generally blocking). Under `uninterruptibleMask`, asynchronous exceptions are completely out of the picture. Also, please note that `allowInterrupt` is *just one of* the interruptible actions; there are a ton more, e.g. `takeMVar`. With just `mask`, it is e.g. impossible to block on an `MVar` without opening yourself up to exceptions, but `uninterruptibleMask` lets you do it (though you shouldn't).

`uninterruptibleCancel` is useful because `cancel` waits for the target thread to finish. This is a blocking operation, so, as is convention, it is also interruptible. Thus, when you use `cancel`, you open yourself up to receiving unexpected exceptions, whether you are `mask`ed or not. When you use `uninterruptibleCancel`, you are 100% guaranteed to not get an exception. That's it. Remember that exceptions are non-local; even if nothing in `cancel` is critical, leaving it unprotected means an exception can leak into something that is.

```
mask $ do
  cancel something -- whoops, this can receive an exception, even though it's masked
  someCleanup -- therefore this might not get called
```

vs.

```
mask $ do
  uninterruptibleCancel something -- no exceptions
  someCleanup -- so this will definitely happen (assuming the target thread ends)
```